# how to use ruby to verify encrypted string what encrypted by java MD5withRSA

Tags: ruby, encryption

Now, i have a string encrypted by java MD5withRSA, i want to verify it through ruby. I have his public key, but i can't verify.

```
def verify?(encrypted_string, origin_string)
  public_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read(PUBLIC_KEY))
  public_key.verify(OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new, Base64.decode64(encrypted_string), origin_string)
end
```

I don't know how MD5withRSA work, and i have tried to use OpenSSL::Digest::MD5.new to verify it...

```
def verify?(encrypted_string, origin_string)
  public_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read(PUBLIC_KEY))
  public_key.verify(OpenSSL::Digest::MD5.new, Base64.decode64(encrypted_string), origin_string)
end
```

Comment: Side note: it will confuse maintainers of your code if you refer to signing as encrypting. You have *signed* data with an RSA private key. No encryption has happened here.

Comment: hi, i have a partner who encrypted data and i just only have to verify it with origin data which can get from other way.

Comment: No, you're still using the wrong terms. Your partner did not encrypt anything, they signed it.

Comment: My partner using MD5withRSA which signs data after md5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rsa = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(publick_key)

rsa.verify('md5', Base64.decode64(sign), rsa_string.force_encoding("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Code dumps don't make for great answers. Can you explain why this code works and the OP's doesn't? Also, why are you assuming UTF-8 string encoding?

Comment: yes, he have explained it by chat, let me explain previous code.

Comment: java's MD5withRSA means raw_encrypt( md5_encrypt( origin_data ) ).      so, using      `rsa.verify('md5', Base64.decode64(sign), rsa_string.force_encoding("utf-8"))`   can verify it.  <br/> if my partner encrypted data with java sha1withRSA, i can use     `rsa.verify('sha1', Base64.decode64(sign), rsa_string.force_encoding("utf-8"))`